# Write single element of array to file

Tags: julia

I try to generate some tests files. These files should look like this:
+ 1 2 3
+ 7 8 15
...
I manage to generate random numbers but I can't write the to a text file.

```
number_of_tests = 5;

rnd_numbers1 = rand(Int128, number_of_tests);
rnd_numbers2 = rand(Int128, number_of_tests);
results = rnd_numbers1 + rnd_numbers2;

open("./t.txt", "w") do f
           for i in 1:number_of_tests
              @printf(f, "+ %d %d %d \n", rnd_numbers1([i], rnd_numbers2[i], results[i]);
           end
       end
```

This is not compiling and the problem is the @printf. I tried write but I couldn't get it work.

Thanks for help

Comment: You say "it is not compiling", can you provide the actual error message you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just made a syntax error. Watch the error messages closely and then the parentheses in your code.

The crucial line should be

```
@printf(f, "+ %d %d %d \n", rnd_numbers1[i], rnd_numbers2[i], results[i]);
```

(there is also the `using Printf` missing, but maybe you just left this out here)

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. using Printf was missing. I haven't done a lot with Julia.